# Django programming: cannot cast time without time zone to timestamp

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am newbie to django and was using SQLite during development, when i moved to postgres when trying to deploy to production i get the below error

Cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone

[image]

settings.py

```
Django settings for todoBackend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
import os
import sys
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS", "127.0.0.1,localhost").split(",")

# Application definition


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "api.apps.ApiConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
ROOT_URLCONF = "todoBackend.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "todoBackend.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False") == "True"
# DEVELOPMENT_MODE = True

if DEVELOPMENT_MODE is True:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != "collectstatic":
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am not sure why i am getting the error, i did setup the timezone in settings.py

The above code was working perfectly with SQLite , It only throws the error in Postgres

Comment: Do you have a migration that changes the type of the end_time field?

Comment: Yes, I convert it from a character field to DateTime Field

Comment: That seems to be your problem. Do you have any data in your production DB? If not then recreating your migrations so that you don't have this conversion would work and be fairly simple. Have any of the migrations for this app be applied successfully?

Comment: Yes the migrations, until the conversion was applied successfully, there is no data in production DB, will try recreating the migrations, Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Try clearing the whole DB, deleting all migration files for that app and then create a single initial migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iain shelvington in the comments pointed out , I had a migration that converted the end_time field from Character field to Time Field, Hence i was getting this error

I reset all my migrations and created a single migration which resolved the issue